Find $m∡MBC$ in the triangle below
In a triangle $ABC$ the median $BM$ is drawn.
Calculate: $m∡MBC$. If: $m∡BAC=\frac{53^o}{2}$, $m∡BCA=\frac{37^o}{2}$
I try:
$a=AM=MC\\
b=BM\\
α=\angle MBC\\
T.senos:\triangle MBC: \frac{a}{senα}=\frac{b}{sen18,5^∘}\\
\triangle ABM: \frac{a}{sen(135^∘−α)}=\frac{b}{sen26,5^∘}⟹\\
\frac{senα}{sen18,5∘}=\frac{sen(135^∘−α)}{sen26,5^∘}⟹\\
\frac{senα⋅sen26,5^∘}{sen18,5^∘}=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}(cosα+senα)⟹⋯\\
⟹tanα=\frac{\frac{\sqrt2}{2}} {\frac{sen26′5∘}{sen18′5∘}−\frac{\sqrt2}{2}}⟹α≃45,33∘
$
s a geometric solution with auxiliary lines possible?


Here is a solution using auxiliary lines as you are asking. See figure below.
Due to the fact that angles $\theta:=53°$ and $37°$ are complementary angles, we can consider $AM$ and $CM$ as line bissectors of right triangle $AB'C$ as shown on the figure, with sides that can assumed  WLOG normalized in this way :
$$AC=1, \ \ B'A=\cos \theta, \ \ B'C=\sin \theta$$
As a consequence, $B$ is the incenter of right triangle $AB'C$.
We are going to establish a certain number of relationships.
First of all, using a specific formula for the inradius of a right triangle (formula (7) here):
$$BH=\frac12(\cos \theta+\sin \theta-1)\tag{0}$$
Besides, due to Euler relationship $d^2=R(R-2r)$ (see page n°3 of this document) where $r$ is the inradius $BH$, $R$ the circumradius $\tfrac12$, and $d$ the distance $BM$, we have :
$$4BM^2=1-4 BH\tag{1}$$
Now, let us consider areas ;

let us remark first that

$$\angle ABC = 180°-\tfrac12(53°+37°)=135°=90°+45°$$
Therefore : $\sin 135° = \sqrt{2}/2$.
Expressing now under two forms the area of triangle $BAC$, we get :
$$\frac12AB.BC \cos 135°=\frac{1}{2}BH.AB \iff AB.BC=\sqrt{2}BH\tag{2}$$

let us express that the areas of triangles $BAM$ and $BMC$ are both equal to the half of the area of triangle $BAC$ :

$$BH=\begin{cases}2BM.BC\sin \alpha\\2BM.AB \sin(135°-\alpha)=2BM.AB(\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha)/\sqrt{2}\end{cases}\tag{3}$$
Out of formulas (3), we get :
$$BH^2=4BM^2 AB.BC \sin\alpha(\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha)\tag{4}$$
Using (1), (2) and simplifying by $BH$ :
$$\underbrace{\frac{BH}{1-4 BH}}_{k}=\sin\alpha(\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha)\tag{5}$$
(5) allows to obtain $\alpha$ because $BH$ has a known value.
For example, using half-angle formulas, $t:=\tan \tfrac12 \alpha$ is a root of fourth degree equation :
$$k=\frac{2t(2t+1-t^2)}{(1+t^2)^2}$$
Remark : This solution with its different steps is not very simple. Maybe shortcuts can be found...

(Geogebra construction downlable here).

Thanks for help...
